# Call JavaScript functionName.method directly

Tags: javascript

Today I ran into a code snippet:

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
} 
myFunction.test = '111';
myFunction.get = function(id) {
    return xxxx;
}
```

Then later the author calls myFunction.get(1) directly. Is it a good practice to call functionName.method or property without initializing it explicitly?

Comment: What else would you expect?

Comment: Do you mean is it bad practice not to call `foo = new myFunction(); foo.get()`?

Comment: there is no prototype here, only static method

Comment: It's not bad practice; this is like a static method in Java.

Comment: @BenM , yes,  would it better to have some sort of instantiation, not necessarily new , objectCreate also can...

Comment: @Purag, any reasons to use this type of static method?

Comment: so it's a bear, a cheerleader and a code snippet that enters a bar, and...

Answer (score 0):

Ya this looks pretty weird to me. I'm not totally clear on the question but I THINK you want to know how to invoke a method aka a function that is an attribute of an object. Consider the following code:

```
//this is an object
var person = {
  name: 'frank',
  job: 'banker',
  //this is a function that's also one of the object's attributes (method)
  speak: function() { 
    console.log('Hi I am a' + this.job + 'named,' + this.name);
  }
};

//we can invoke the method like this
person.speak() //Hi I am a banker named, frank
```

Hope that's what you were looking for.